# How to redirect to a view in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller

I was trying to make a redirect from the main page of a spring project to another view, but I get a 404 even if I've checked most online resources and did exactly as I was shown. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect")
public ModelAndView redirect(){

   return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("check"));

}
```

dispathcher-servlet.xml :

```
<bean class="mine.Controllers.MainController" name="mainController" lazy-init="false" ></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="resolver">
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Views/"></property>
    <property name="order" value="1"></property>
</bean>
```

index.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Click <a href="/redirect">here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a screenshot of my project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UeSZ.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedirectView class constructor argument is "URL" not "view name"

To make it work Your example add this code in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "check")
public ModelAndView check(){

return new ModelAndView("check");

}
```

and change redirect method code to this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect")
public RedirectView redirect(){

return new RedirectView("check");

}
```

Comment: I've let ,,check" as the argument because that was my last attempt. I've tried check.jsp , /check.jsp , /check , /Views/check.jsp and /Views/check. Can you tell me please what is would be the correct url based on my project structure so I can try again with that exact url?

Comment: Just add the code i have posted, try and let me know

Comment: Yeap, now it works. I mean, I get an error regarding my jsp, but the point is that the redirect worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect to another url by using`"redirect:url"` from controller method or return RedirectView directly.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect")
public String redirect(){
    String redirectUrl = "YOUR_URL";
    return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;

}
```

Comment: I've tried returning directrly that RedirectView I used as an argument for the ModelAndView and when I tried to return a string with the redirect prefix it just got displayed on the page